# How can I reference the name of the previous array item in this Rails ERB mark-up loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a Rails noob. I am generating a menu in an ERB template, looping through the array "elements":

```
    <% @elements.each do |element| -%>
        <div class="category <%= element.category.color %>">
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

I want to add an additional class to each item (except the first, obviously), referencing the element.category.color of the PREVIOUS item, so that the final mark-up looks like:

```
  <div class="category blue">I am the first, no extra class</div>
  <div class="category green after-blue">I come after blue</div>
  <div class="category yellow after-green">I come after green</div>
```

This is all basically a work-around to avoid using next-sibling CSS selectors, which are slow as hell in some of the browsers I need to support, and causing rendering problems when changing the background colours of the items.

Can I add the class I want directly in the ERB, or will I need to also use the controller to calculate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
<% @elements.each_with_index do |element, index| -%>
  <div class=<%= "category #{element.category.color} " + ("after-#{@elements[index-1].category.color}" unless index == 0) %>>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
<% prev = '' %>
<% @elements.each do |element| -%>
    <div class=<%= "category #{element.category.color}#{' after-' + prev if prev.present?}" %>>
    <% prev = element.category.color %>        
    </div>
<% end %>
```